# jQuery - set one input equal to 5% of another and more 1

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two input fields - a donation and a tip field.  I need to set the tip field equal to 5% of the donation field when the donation field is changed.  And I need to make sure both fields are never less than $1.

I have this, but it's not working correctly:

```
$('#donationAmount').change(function() {
    var donationAmount = $('#donationAmount');
    var tipAmount = $('#tipAmount');

    if(parseFloat(tipAmount.val()) <= 1){
        tipAmount.val(1);
    }else{
        tipAmount.val(parseFloat(donationAmount.val()*0.05).toFixed(2));
    }

    if(parseFloat(donationAmount.val()) < 1){
        donationAmount.val(1);
    }
});
```

Comment: So check if the tipAmount value is less than a dollar after the calculation.... Some reason you do it before you calculate it....

Comment: You should use PHP for payments. Javascript and any Frontend based language can be edited by your visitors. You should create a form with a checkbox `<input type="checkbox" name="donationtip" id="donationtip"><label for="donationtip">Would you like to leave a tip?</label>` If it's a donation and not a payment, why you need a tip ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below should grab the donation amount and if it's below $1.00 set it to $1.00, then calculate the tip at 5% and if it's below $1.00 set it to a $1.00 and repopulate both fields.  I would recommend validating on the back end as well since the field can be changed to arbitrary value in a number of ways.

```
$('#donationAmount').on('change', function(){ 
  var $donationAmount = $(this);
  var $tipAmount = $('#tipAmount');

  var donation = Number($donationAmount.val());
  var tip;

  donation = (donation >= minimum)? donation:1;
  tip = (donation*0.05 >= minimum)? donation*0.05:1;

  $donationAmount.val( donation.toFixed(2) );
  $tipAmount.val( tip.toFixed(2) );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the tip amount (to see if it is at least $1) after the calculating 5% of the donation amount instead of before.

Tip must be at least 5% of donation:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Donation Amount:
<input type="number" id="donationAmount"/><p/>
Tip Amount:
<input type="number" id="tipAmount"/>
<script>
$('#donationAmount').change(function() {
    var donationAmount = $('#donationAmount');
    var tipAmount = $('#tipAmount');
    var donation = parseFloat(donationAmount.val());
    var tip = parseFloat(tipAmount.val());
    if(donation<1){
      donation = 1;
      donationAmount.val(1);
    }
    if(tip/donation<0.05){
     tipAmount.val((donation*0.05).toFixed(2));
    }
    if(tipAmount.val()<1){
     tipAmount.val(1);
    }
});
</script>
```

Tip must be exactly 5% of donation:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Donation Amount:
<input type="number" id="donationAmount"/><p/>
Tip Amount:
<input type="number" id="tipAmount"/>
<script>
$('#donationAmount').change(function() {
    var donationAmount = $('#donationAmount');
    var tipAmount = $('#tipAmount');
    var donation = parseFloat(donationAmount.val());
    var tip = parseFloat(tipAmount.val());
    if(donation<1){
      donation = 1;
      donationAmount.val(1);
    }
    if(tip/donation!=0.05){
     tipAmount.val((donation*0.05).toFixed(2));
    }
    if(tipAmount.val()<1){
     tipAmount.val(1);
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Your solution allows a tip greater than 5%... It may be correct for OP, but just to mention....

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette That would seem logical: tip must be at least 5% of donation amount.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette I have edited my code for both possibilities.

Comment: It also allows the "donation" to be less than 1.

Comment: *« I need to make sure **both** fields are never less than $1»*

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Thanks for telling me. I have fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You criterias:

1. Tip must be 5% of donation
2. Both must be 1.00 of greater

You need to compare two values to a "minimum". The first is the value entered by the user and the second is the result of a calculation.

To shorten the code and to make it easier to read, I used some [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) instead of if/else statements.

Here are the steps in order (and that was the main cause of your issue):

1. get the input.
2. check if it is greater than the `minimum` to set the `donation`.
3. do the 5% `math`
4. check if `math` is greater than `minimum` to set the `tip`.

Both values were compared and possibly replaced by the minimum.

5. send the two correct values to the input elements.

```js
$('#donationAmount').change(function(){
  var minimum = 1.00;
  var donation_input = parseFloat($(this).val());
  var donation = (donation_input<minimum) ? minimum : donation_input;
  
  var math = donation*0.05;
  var tip = (math<minimum) ? minimum : math;

  $(this).val(donation.toFixed(2));
  $("#tipAmount").val(tip.toFixed(2));

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Donation: <input type="text" id="donationAmount"><br>
Tip: <input type="text" id="tipAmount">
```